# Why could an object's state be a subset of the fields in the object graph rooted at that object?

Tags: java, oop

I'm reading "Java concurrency in practice", at first, it says:

> An object's state starts with its fields. If they are all of primitive type, the fields comprise the entire state.
>
> If the object has fields that are references to other objects, its state will encompass fields from the referenced objects as well.

Then it says:

> an object's state could be a subset of the fields in the object graph rooted at that object. Why might it be a subset? Under what conditions are fields reachable from a given object not part of that object's state?

I can't find the answers to the two questions in the book.

- **Why might it be a subset?**
- **Under what conditions are fields reachable from a given object not part of that object's state?**

And I'm totally confused with the above two quotes. It seems contradictory to me. Can someone give an example which can show "an object's state is a subset of the fields in the object graph rooted at that object" and answer those two questions?

Comment: Perhaps they refer to static fields as not being included as being part of an object's state

Comment: The next sentence states: "*When defining which variables form an object’s state, we want to consider only the data that object owns*" - The first question is answered with the `HashMap` example, and I believe the answer to the 2nd question is expressed in the collection example: "*Collection classes often exhibit a form of “split ownership”, in which the collection owns the state of the collection infrastructure, but client code owns the objects stored in the collection*"

Comment: @VinceEmigh Does ownership mean [the responsibility of taking care of thread safety](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11341347/5232255)? If the answer is yes, then if I have a list of objects, the objects are not owned by the list (means objects are not part of list's state), but the list has fields about objects (means objects are part of list's state). It seems contradictory to me.

Comment: Yes, the book states: "*It is the owner of a given state variable that gets to decide on the locking protocol used to maintain the integrity of that variable’s state*". And you're right, the list has a field of objects, which is why it's considered/coined "split ownership". The collection owns the containment of the objects (I.E. array), but does not have exclusive ownership of the objects in said container.

Comment: Although the container holds the objects, the state of those objects do not affect the container, thus the state of those objects should not be considered a subset of the collection's state. Keep in mind: "*Ownership is not embodied explicitly in the language, but is instead an element of class design.*" - You won't find any explicit notion of these ideas in the language itself, rather it's on us to determine ownership. The main idea is to pinpoint who owns state to determine who should control the locking protocol.

Comment: (Continued) Since collections cannot control the safety of it's elements state, it's not considered a subset of the collection's state - the collection owns the container, but not the objects the container holds.

Comment: @VinceEmigh So, why is the statement "If the object has fields that are references to other objects, its state will encompass fields from the referenced objects as well." true?

Comment: Because the changing state of an object may affect the object that's composed of it. The same can't be said for elements of a collection, where the elements' state cannot affect the state of the collection. I agree it should be more explicit about the term "split ownership", but in practice, there's no way for the collection to control the safety of it's elements, and that's the idea being expressed. "*Servlets need not use synchronization when calling setAttribute and getAttribute, but they may have to use synchronization when using the objects stored in the ServletContext*"

Comment: @VinceEmigh Thank you do much, but I still having trouble understanding "If the object has fields that are references to other objects, its state will encompass fields from the referenced objects as well.", I think the meaning is "all fields reachable from am object are part of the object's state". Isn't it? Where do I get wrong?

Comment: If that were true, there would be no purpose for "*Under what conditions are fields reachable from a given object not part of that object’s state?*". The book doesn't say *all* fields will be encompassed, only that fields are encompassed. The second question, along with the collection example "*the collection owns the state of the collection infrastructure, but client code owns the objects stored in the collection*" makes it clear that not *all* reachable fields are considered to be owned.

Comment: Let me know if you still have any confusions on this topic. Your issue seemed to be the insertion of the word *all*, which is not only non-existent in the book, but there exists many statements contradicting that, such as "*We implied in Section 4.1 that an object’s state **could** be a subset of the fields in the object graph rooted at that object.*" - It *could* be, but there's nothing stating it must be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Quick Answer

From the comments, your confusion seems to be:

> I think the meaning is "all fields reachable from am object are part of the object's state". Isn't it?

No, that's not the meaning. This is expressed by the question the author asks:

> *Under what conditions are fields reachable from a given object not part of that object's state?*

Which is answered soon after:

> Collection classes often exhibit a form of “split ownership”, in which **the collection owns the state of the collection infrastructure, but client code owns the
>   objects stored in the collection**

---

## Understanding Ownership

For clarity, ownership determines who may implement a synchronization policy for that state.

> In many cases, ownership and encapsulation go together—the object encapsulates the state it owns and owns the state it encapsulates. It is the owner of a given state variable that gets to decide on the locking protocol used to maintain the integrity of that variable’s state

When state is encapsulated, clients are forced to interact with the state through whatever encapsulated it. Thus, the encapsulator is the exclusive owner, and thread-safety is determined by the exclusive owner.

> once you publish a reference to a mutable object, you no longer have exclusive control; at best, you might have “shared ownership”.

If the object is exposed (possibly through a getter), the encapsulator loses *exclusive* ownership, as the client may now by-pass any policies set by the encapsulator.

However, this doesn't change the fact that the object is still *partially* owned by the encapsulator - the encapsulator may still enforce it's policy when clients modify the object's state through the encapsulator.

---

## Answer for..

> Why may it be a subset?

From the book:

> If you allocate and populate a `HashMap`, you are creating multiple objects: the `HashMap` object, a number of `Map.Entry` objects used by the implementation of `HashMap`, and perhaps other internal objects as well.

A `HashMap` is composed of potentially many `Map.Entry` objects, in the form of [`HashMap#Node`](https://github.com/bpupadhyaya/openjdk-8/blob/master/jdk/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#L278-L316).

Since `HashMap` has control over how clients interact with `Node` (clients may not create new `Node` instances, only through methods such as `HashMap#putVal` which determines state such as `Node#hash`), the state of `Node` is considered to be a subset of `HashMap`.

---

## Answer for...

> Under what conditions are fields reachable from a given object not part of that object's state?

From the book:

> Collection classes often exhibit a form of “split ownership”, in which the collection owns the state of the collection infrastructure, but client code owns the
>   objects stored in the collection.
>
> ---
>
> Servlets need not use synchronization when calling set-
>   Attribute and getAttribute, but they may have to use synchronization when using the objects stored in the ServletContext

Collections have no control over the thread safety of it's elements - clients may have to implement their own synchronization when using elements received from the collection.

Since the collection has no control over the thread-safety of it's elements, it does not own the state of it's elememts; elements' state is not a subset of the collection's state, only the infrastructure is.